# Correct way to call methods on an object (class) from a router?

Tags: javascript, node.js

First, I apologize for the ambiguous title. Briefly, this is what I am trying to achieve.
I have to components:

1. A class (wallet.js)
2. A router (index.js) which serves GET requests

This is what I am trying to do:

In the app.js where the initialization takes place, I instantiate an object of NeworkConnection class:

```
(async () => {
    var wallet = require('./modules/wallet')(params);
})();
```

It is in an `async` block because there are some asynchronous calls.

Now what I want to do is something like this in the `router/index.js`:

```
    router.get('/getBalance', function(req, res, next) {
        wallet.getBalance();
        ...
      })
```

My question is, what is the best way to achieve this? How can I pass the initialized `wallet` object to the `index` router to call methods in the Wallet class?

Thank you.

Comment: That doesn't make much sense right.....module/wallet definition itself is on runtime? Can't u define wallet module earlier and do call async functions on it on runtime?

Comment: It is a class actually. And I export it `module.exports = (params) => {return new  WalletClass(params) };`

Comment: @madu What exactly is asynchronous there? Please post the complete code. You are not using the local `wallet` variable in that IIFE, and you are not doing `await` anywhere so there's no need to make it `async`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### IGNORE THIS

If you really want to instantiate them in a separate file - (possibly because you are gonna use it in different places?) I think the following would work:

```
// app.js

let wallet;

(async () => {
   wallet = require('./modules/wallet')(params);
})();

module.exports = {
   wallet
}
```

Then just require it in your router's index.js:

```
// index.js
const wallet = require('./app').wallet;

router.get('/getBalance', function(req, res, next) {
    wallet.getBalance();
    ...
})
```

### THIS WORKS

I created a dummy example that works. Consider the following:

```
// wallet.js
let wallet;

class Wallet {
    constructor () {
        this.name = 'NAME!';
    }
}

// just a way to simulate the asynchronous instantiation of your wallet
async function initWallet() {
    return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
            if (!wallet) {
                setTimeout( () => {
                    console.log('instantiating...');
                    wallet = new Wallet();
                    resolve(wallet);
                }, 2000)
            } else {
                console.log('already exists!');
                resolve(wallet);
            }


    });
}

module.exports = {
    initWallet
}
```

```
// wallet2.js (a second file that also uses wallet. 
// This will be used to check that indeed when the function 
// initWallet is called multiple times, 
// the returned objects refer to a singleton object)
const initWallet = require('./mod').initWallet;

module.exports = {
    secondInitWallet: initWallet
};
```

```
const initWallet = require('./wallet').initWallet;
const secondInitWallet = require('./wallet2').secondInitWallet;

let wallet;

router.get('/getBalance', async function(req, res, next) {
    wallet = await initWallet();
    wallet.getBalance();
    ...
    wallet2 = await secondInitWallet();

    // just to make sure that the instantiated object is a singleton
    console.log(wallet, wallet2);
    wallet.name = 'CHANGED NAME!';
    console.log(wallet, wallet2);
})
```

Comment: Thank you! This looks like exactly what I need but when I `require(./app).wallet` in `index.js` wallet is undefined. I did `module.exports.app = app;
module.exports.wallet = wallet;` because `app.js` exports `app` also.

Comment: Don't do this. This might cause an exception when the router handles a request while the `wallet` is not yet initialised.

Comment: @Bergi is right, I modified the code to correct for this. Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the update. You'll want to make the `wallet` a local variable in the getBalance handler though, no need to store it in the module scope where it could potentially overwritten.

Comment: Btw, in your `initWallet` you will want to cache the promise itself, not the `wallet` value, as otherwise you'd be creating multiple `new Wallet`s if `initWallet` is called multiple times before the first one is created.

Answer (score 2):

You can just initialise the `wallet` in your route/controller file. But doing that will result in making every user using same wallet. Because the application is single one.

So basically, you need to use `session` and for each session you need to instantiate a wallet object.

Let's say you have a route `/login` where you are setting the session.

**router.js**

```
const express = require('express');

const router = express.Router();

const Wallet = require('wallet');

const wallets = {};

router.post('/login',async (req,res)=>{
  //login
  wallets[req.sessionID] = new Wallet()//or something
  //the async calls
  res.json({
    success:true
  })
});

router.get('/getBalance', auth /*to check if logged in*/, (req,res)=>{
  const wallet = wallets[req.sessionID];
  wallet.getBalance();
});

module.exports = router;
```

Basically this is how you can do it, take it as hint to a general direction.